# How to get W4InstanceId in C# from with in a list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, development, workflow-manager

I have a list called `Students` on which there is a workflow running called `StudentWorkflow`.

I want to loop through all list items in `Students` and retrieve their related `W4InstanceId` from `Workflow Tasks` list. How can I do that in C#?

Tried the following but it doesn't display anything because it doesn't go inside that second for loop:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["Students"];
                    foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                    {
                        foreach (SPWorkflow wf in item.Workflows) //doesn't go inside
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.ID + " " + wf.InstanceId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```